# Problema con el manifest al cambiar el target a android 12

Tags: java, android, android-studio, app, android-manifest

Estaba creando una app y empezaron a salirme errores. Como no supe solucionarlos he vuelto a empezar en otro proyecto pero ahora me sale un error que con el otro no me salía.

> Error: Manifest merger failed : Apps targeting Android 12 and higher
> are required to specify an explicit value for `android:exported` when
> the corresponding component has an intent filter defined.

Este es mi manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.appjava2">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppJava2"
        android:exported="false"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="false">


        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

¿Cómo puedo solucionar este problema?

Comment: Esta pregunta ya la pusiste ayer y fue cerrada por falta de información. Debes añadir el código y no imágenes de el.

Comment: No se que ha pasado porque soy nueva y la cuenta no se creo bien o algo asi que no la puedo ver. Lo siento

Comment: Lectura recomendada: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4433/822

Comment: Bueno, para obtener el texto de un EditText es así: edditText.getText().toString().trim(); y dentro del case no debes volver a hacer la comprobación con un if().

Comment: ¿Probaste cambiando esto `android:exported="false"` por esto `android:exported="true"`? @MarPuigPuig

Comment: Hola Mar Puig Puig, lo que indicas se soluciona con <activity android:name=".MainActivity" android:exported="true"> pero es importante revises el LogCat, agrega el mensaje de error ya que debes tener mas problemas en tu app.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ese es uno de los [cambios introducidos en android 12](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/12/behavior-changes-12#exported). Como dice el mensaje, los componentes de tu aplicación que tengan un *intent filter* deben declarar explícitamente el atributo `android:exported`.

Definitivamente deberías leer [qué es un componente](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fundamentals#Components) porque agregaste el atributo en la etiqueta `application`, donde no es válido. La solución es quitarlo de ahí y colocarlo en la etiqueta `activity` con el valor `true`

```
<activity android:name=".MainActivity" android:exported="true">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

El valor necesariamente tiene que ser `true` para que el launcher y otras aplicaciones puedan lanzar esa activity. De lo contrario tu aplicación no se podrá iniciar. Puedes encontrar más información sobre el atributo `android:exported` en la [documentación](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element#exported).

Comment: Muchas gracias el error ja no sale pero la app sigue sin funcionar, se abre pero al momento se cierra.

Comment: Gracias a todos por los consejos.

Comment: Crea otra pregunta mostrando tu código y el error que se ve en el logcat

Answer (score 0):

El componente `android:exported`debes de aplicarlo a la actividad no a la aplicación.

Si le das el valor `true` cuando lances la app en un emulador se abre automáticamente la actividad. Por el contrario, el valor `false`, precisa que una vez ejecutes la app en el emulador tendrás que clicar el icono para ejecutar la actividad.